# Appcelerator. Using swipe to open window

Tags: appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator and I want to switch between windows with the use of a swipe event listener. How can I do this? The below code does not work. The current window that I "start" from contains a table.

```
var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

window.addEventListener('swipe', function() {

    // Create the new window

    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

        title: 'Contacts',  
        url:'contacts_simple.js'

    });

    // Animate the page turn

    Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win, {animated:false});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the Ti.UI.currentWindow. Depending on the context you're working in it may not be valid.

Google 'appcelerator currentWindow', but here's a related link:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/5391/currentwindow

This will not be optimal and dynamic, but to start with, try referencing the window implicitly. Meaning if you did something like

```
var window_x = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
```

try

```
window_x.addEventListener('swipe', function() {...});
```